# Next.js app in docker listens on the wrong interface

Tags: next.js, docker-compose

I have a NextJS app that needa a MySQL database. I create a container for the app and a container for the MySQL database.

Both containers are included in a docker-compose stack, grades_web and grades_mysql

Networks:

- sys_apps_net / 10.200.5.x - connects the app to a reverse proxy and thus to the outside world
- grades_web_db / 10.200.7.x - connects the app to the MySQL container

grades_web container has two IPs

- 10.200.7.2 - on grades_web_db
- 10.200.5.3 - on sys_apps_net

To start the container I set HOSTNAME=0.0.0.0, so  NextJS should listen on all IPs.
The App is built in standalone mode.

When the container starts , it says

```
   ▲ Next.js 13.5.3
   - Local:        http://b0772d4dfb3c:3000
   - Network:      http://10.200.7.2:3000
```

This tells me that the app listens on 10.200.7.2 only. Therefore it is not reachable by the reverse proxy and the outside world.

What can I do to make the app listen on all IP addresses?

NextJS 13.5.3
MySQL 8.1
Docker 24.0.6

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:20-alpine AS dependencies

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install


FROM node:20-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=dependencies /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN npx prisma generate
RUN npx next telemetry disable
RUN npm run build

FROM node:20-alpine AS deploy
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV production

COPY --from=build /app/public ./public
COPY --from=build /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=build /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=build /app/.next/static ./.next/static
COPY --from=build /app/prisma ./prisma

EXPOSE 3000
ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:migrate:prod"]
```

**docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: gdr.htl-villach.at/htl-it/htl-it-docker-registry/grades:0.9
    container_name: grades_web
    restart: unless-stopped

    networks: 
      - sys_apps_net
      - web_db

    environment:
      HOST: 0.0.0.0
      DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
      NEXTAUTH_URL: ${NEXTAUTH_URL}
      NEXTAUTH_SECRET: ${NEXTAUTH_SECRET}
      AZURE_CLIENT_ID: ${AZURE_CLIENT_ID}
      AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: ${AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET}
      AZURE_TENANT_ID: ${AZURE_TENANT_ID}

  db:
    image: mysql:8.1
    container_name: grades_mysql
    restart: unless-stopped

    networks: 
      - web_db

    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: ${MYSQL_ROOT_HOST}

volumes:
  mysql_data:

networks:
  web_db:
    external: false
  sys_apps_net:
    external: true
```

**package.json**

```
...
 "scripts": {
   ...
   "start:migrate:prod": "HOSTNAME=0.0.0.0 npx prisma migrate deploy && node prisma/seed.mjs && node server.js"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Experience often comes after it was needed.

The culprit was the start script:
Move `HOSTNAME=0.0.0.0` from

```
   "start:migrate:prod": "HOSTNAME=0.0.0.0 npx prisma migrate deploy && node prisma/seed.mjs && node server.js"
```

to

```
    "start:migrate:prod": "npx prisma migrate deploy && node prisma/seed.mjs && HOSTNAME=0.0.0.0 node server.js"
```

`server.js` will happily pick up `HOSTNAME` and the startup log will tell us:

```
 ▲ Next.js 13.5.3
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000
   - Network:      http://0.0.0.0:3000
```